# onClick on GlSufaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, webrtc, glsurfaceview

I am working on GLSufaceView with local and remote stream.I set the remote and local stream using VideoRenderer as show below.[image]

Small view is remote streaming.I want to exchange local and remote video streaming on click of remote view and the problem is I am not able to apply click on this view.I am using this code to add remote and video stream.

```
    remoteRender = VideoRendererGui.create(REMOTE_X, REMOTE_Y, REMOTE_WIDTH, REMOTE_HEIGHT, scalingType, false);
    localRender = VideoRendererGui.create(LOCAL_X_CONNECTING, LOCAL_Y_CONNECTING, LOCAL_WIDTH_CONNECTING, LOCAL_HEIGHT_CONNECTING, scalingType, true);
```

when I get my local stream below mention method is called:

```
     @Override
public void onLocalStream(MediaStream stream) {
    stream.videoTracks.get(0).addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(localRender));
    VideoRendererGui.update(localRender, LOCAL_X_CONNECTING, LOCAL_Y_CONNECTING, LOCAL_WIDTH_CONNECTING, LOCAL_HEIGHT_CONNECTING, scalingType, true);
}
```

and when I get remote stream below mention method is called:

```
      @Override
public void onAddRemoteStream(final MediaStream remoteStream, final int endPoint, final PeerConnection pc) {

   remoteRender = VideoRendererGui.create(REMOTE_X_CONNECTED - 20 * (cursor - 1), y, REMOTE_WIDTH_CONNECTED, REMOTE_HEIGHT_CONNECTED, scalingType, false);
            remoteStream.videoTracks.get(0).addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(remoteRender));
            VideoRendererGui.update(remoteRender, REMOTE_X_CONNECTED - 20 * (cursor - 1), y, REMOTE_WIDTH_CONNECTED, REMOTE_HEIGHT_CONNECTED, scalingType, true);

        }
    });
}
```

I want to apply click on only remote stream.While both views are the part of one GLSurfaceview.

Please help me regarding this issue.

Comment: What have you tried to solve this issue and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Actually I am using GLSurfaceView and to add remote and local view I have used this VideoRendererGui.create() method to create view and its working fine but I am stuck on the issue to apply click on this view.When I try to apply click on it then its working for whole GLSufaceView and I just want to apply click on remoteview only.

Comment: What code? I don't see any code in your question, but a very large nice image instead.

Comment: I have edited the comment so plz check .

Comment: I suggest/recommend you to edit your question now and insert this code.

Comment: okay I edited the question now plz help me to get out of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to use 2 surface views, stacked one on top of the other using a FrameLayout. You then attach an onClickListener to the one you want to listen for clicks

```
remoteVideoView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.remote_view);
localVideoView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.local_view);

remoteVideoView.setOnCLickListener(view -> switchStreams());
```